# How can I transfer data from HDFS to Oracle using Apache Nifi?

Tags: apache-nifi

I am new to Nifi and looking for information on using Nifi processors to get speed upto 100MB/s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first you should use getHdfs processor to retrive HDFS file as flowfile.

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-hadoop-nar/1.11.4/org.apache.nifi.processors.hadoop.GetHDFS/index.html

to put data into Oracle, you can use the PutDatabaseRecord Processor :

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.11.4/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.PutDatabaseRecord/

between them, it's depend of your requirement, you can use ExecuteGroovyScript for exemple to transform your flowfile into query.

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-groovyx-nar/1.11.4/org.apache.nifi.processors.groovyx.ExecuteGroovyScript/index.html

all processor avaible : https://nifi.apache.org/docs.html